# Vectorization and optimization of matrix subtraction

Tags: numpy, vectorization

Is it possible to vectorize / optimize the following loop?

```
In [33]: a = np.arange(10000 * 700).reshape([10000, 700])

In [34]: b = np.arange(1000 * 700).reshape([1000, 700])

In [35]: c = np.empty([b.shape[0], a.shape[0]])

In [36]: for i in range(b.shape[0]):
    ...:     c[i] = np.argsort(np.linalg.norm(a - b[i], axis=1))
    ...:
```

---

**Edit:**

I believe the following should work:

```
d = np.argsort(np.linalg.norm(a[:, None] - b, axis=2), axis=1)
```

But I'm getting `MemoryError` for `a[:, None] - b`. Am I in the right direction? What can be done regarding the `MemoryError`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way would be with [`cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) -

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

cdist(b,a).argsort(axis=1)
```

Equivalent one with [`pairwise_distances`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances.html) -

```
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances

pairwise_distances(b,a).argsort(1)
```

Timings for given sample data -

```
In [201]: %%timeit # original solution
     ...: c = np.empty([b.shape[0], a.shape[0]],dtype=int)
     ...: for i in range(b.shape[0]):
     ...:     c[i] = np.argsort(np.linalg.norm(a - b[i], axis=1))
1 loop, best of 3: 40.6 s per loop

In [202]: %timeit pairwise_distances(b,a).argsort(1)
1 loop, best of 3: 384 ms per loop
```

**`100x+`** speedup!

Comment: Thanks! Can this also be done using `sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances`?

Comment: @galah92 Yup - `pairwise_distances(b,a).argsort(1)`.

Comment: Since you are only interested in the order you can leave out the `np.einsum('ij,ij->i',b,b)[:,None]` which is constant along the sort axis.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Good point, thanks! Figured that method wasn't efficient enough.